# Bash smart command history search not working

Tags: bash

I have my history file set up, echo INPUTRC shows the right file in my home directory as well.

The contents of the inputrc file in my home directory is

```
"\e[A~": history-search-forward
"\e[B~": history-search-backward
```

I am not sure why, but when I type some chars and try to use the "up" arrow to give me the last matching command from my history, what I get is simply the last command used from history.

Note that when I set the `inputrc` contents to the lines below (pg up and pg down) it seems to work!

```
"\e[5~": history-search-forward
#"\e[A~": history-search-forward
#"\e[B~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-backward
```

Comment: Is `\e[A~` what gets send for the up arrow key? Have you checked?

Comment: i tried cat command and then pressed up arrow, this is what showed on the screen
^[[A

EDIT: removing the ~ from the inputrc works, thanks for the help muru!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the arrow keys you are using are not recognized by your terminal emulator, and therefore are not being sent to Bash as expected. Try using the arrow keys in a different terminal emulator to see if the behavior is the same.

If that doesn't solve the issue, you can try adding the following lines to your `~/.inputrc` file to enable incremental search:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

This maps the up arrow key to search backward through the history and the down arrow key to search forward. Make sure to restart your terminal after making changes to the `~/.inputrc` file.

Comment: Thanks kuspia, this works! removing the ~ worked for me